# signing documents in O365 electronically

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are working on signing documents in O365 electronically, in order to do it, we need to access them as a file or a data strem, this is the code we are using in order to electronically sign a pdf document.

Stream archivoPdf = new FileStream(pdfCon, FileMode.Create);

```
PdfReader firmapdf = new PdfReader(pdfSin);
PdfStamper fir = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(firmapdf, archivoPdf, '\0');
```

On the first line we take the path where the file can be obtained. And the 2nd line we invoke the signing method.
In the case of onedrive we have only been able to move froward via the logical path using the API sample from onedrive with JavaScript

```
"size": 17358,
  "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/x/s!AEuukj7rjH7VjH8",
  "file": {
    "hashes": {
      "crc32Hash": "E248ECFD",
      "sha1Hash": "673102CFAAF6B3C13DAC3E850FE51B0DA8834104"
    },
    "mimeType": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
  },
  "fileSystemInfo": {
    "createdDateTime": "2015-03-12T13:45:04.52Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2015-03-12T13:21:08Z"
  },
  "children@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('xxxxxxxxx%40hotmail.com')/drive/root/children",
  "children": [],
  "thumbnails@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('xxxxxxxxx%40hotmail.com')/drive/root/thumbnails",
  "thumbnails": []
```

This is not allowing the handling of the file for electronic signing.

What we need to do is to be able to list and be able to handle and sign files and folders in one drive

Comment: Have you looked at the upload/download APIs in Graph? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent

Comment: We have used for testing https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v72/js-picker-overview.htm. Question: Can we use OneDrive file picker for JavaScript v7.2 to select files inside a folder in OneDrive and then send the signed file to an output library within OneDrive? @markstafford